# How to order method calling in angular material select

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have an angular material multiple selection drop-down. There is the 'All' option in that dropdown. Whenever an option is selected, a method(let's call this method 01) will be called.Also when the 'all' option is selected, another method(let's call this method 02) will be called alongside with the method 01.But the method 01 is being called before method 02. I want the method 02 to be called and completed first, before method 01 is called, when 'All' is clicked.Your help is much appreciated.

This is the dropdown.

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="unitForm">
  <mat-label>{{ 'Units' }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select  [placeholder]="'Units'" (selectionChange)="change($event)" formControlName="unitControl" multiple>
    <mat-option #allSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="0"> All </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let unit of orgUnits" [value]="unit.id">
      {{ unit.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdrk6p

I could have used one method instead of two methods but I  want to get hold of the moments where the user deselects the inner 'All' option. the outermethod tracks only selected options but doesn't provide deselected values. Is there any way to get the deselected values? (deselct means not unchecked values apart from the checked values, but the values which were checked before and are now unchecked by the user)

Answer (score 1):

hello this is my solution:

```js
import {
  Component
} from "@angular/core";

export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: "select-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "select-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["select-overview-example.css"]
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [{
      value: "steak-0",
      viewValue: "Steak"
    },
    {
      value: "pizza-1",
      viewValue: "Pizza"
    },
    {
      value: "tacos-2",
      viewValue: "Tacos"
    }
  ];

  outerMethod(flag) {
    if (flag == 0) this.innerMethod();
    alert("outer");
  }

  innerMethod() {
    alert("inner");
  }
}

/**  Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

```html
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="outerMethod($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="0"> All </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track adding mat checkbox inside matselect. We are tracking it by allSelected variable and event value passed by all checkbox. For other checked values you can write code after /** For other values **/

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="outerMethod()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods let i = index" [value]="food.value">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="selected === i" (change)="onCheckboxChange(food);selected = i"> {{food.viewValue}}</mat-checkbox> 
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="0"><mat-checkbox (change)="onCheckboxChange(0);"> All</mat-checkbox>   </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In component.ts

import { Component } from "@angular/core";

```
export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: "select-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "select-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["select-overview-example.css"]
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    { value: "steak-0", viewValue: "Steak" },
    { value: "pizza-1", viewValue: "Pizza" },
    { value: "tacos-2", viewValue: "Tacos" }
  ];
  selected= -1;
  allSelected:false;


  /*Track checkbox events*/
  onCheckboxChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(event === 0 && !this.allSelected){
      this.allSelected = true;
    }else if(event === 0 && this.allSelected){
      this.allSelected = false;
    }
    console.log(this.allSelected);
    /** For other values **/
  }

}
```

Link to stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdrk6p-hgt32o